# Firebase Functions: Variables undefined onCall

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, web-services, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a project in which I try to pass variables from my Angular front-end to my Firebase back-end. However I am running into an issue in the code below. I'm trying to use variables stored in the data array but in the Firebase console they come up as undefined. I've tried making a nodeJS project and running this code and it seems to work fine... What can be the issue?

P.S. I've also tried passing an object as well but the result is the same.

This is the index.ts of my functions folder:

```
import * as nodemailer from 'nodemailer';


// // Start writing Firebase Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript
//
export const sendMail = functions.https.onCall((data) => {

    

    console.log(data.text);
    const name = data[0];
    const email = data[1];
    const phoneNumber = data[2];
    const title = data[3];
    const body = data[4];

   const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "smtp.gmail.com",
      port: 465,
      secure: true, 
      auth: {
          user: 'xxxxxxx',
          pass: 'xxxxxxxx',
      },
  });

  transporter.sendMail({
      from: 'xxxxxxx',
      to: "xxxxxxxx",
      subject: title,
      html: "<b>Message send by:<br></b>" + email + "<br><br>" + body,
  }).catch((_e: Error) => {
    const e:Error = _e
    console.log(e);
  });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameters that are passed to callable Cloud Functions are named, and not ordered. So unless you somehow named the parameters `0` and `1`, it is unlikely that your lookup works.

I recommend checking the code that calls this Cloud Function and using the names used in that code here too. If you've used the names `name` and `email` in the calling code, the Cloud Function would look like:

```
const name = data.name;
const email = data.email;
```

---

If you want to verify what parameters ere being passed to the Cloud Function without looking at the code that calls it, you can log the data object with:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: I have tried using an object instead of an array but the results seems to be the same. Thanks for your fast reply btw.

Comment: Did you try toe `console.log`? What does it show? Also: since this depends on how the calling code passes the parameters, it might be good to see the minimal code for that call too.

Comment: I did upvote but I need more rep to do so. Eventually I just gave up and searched for a workaround. Thanks for the help though!